# Condition Based Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have the following tables

1. Invoice
2. Organization
3. Customer

I'm trying to conditionally join these tables by the following condition: If PTypecd = 'I' then data come from the Customer table And if Ptypecd = 'O' then data come from the Organization table into the Invoice table.

the query i tried so far:

```
Select 
    I.PCD, I.PtypeCD,    
From 
    Invoice I 
Left Join 
    Customer C ON I.PCD = C.CustomerCD 
Left Join 
    Organization O ON I>PDC = O.Organization
```

How does this condition be used in Join?

Comment: Include `PTypecd` in the `ON` and then use `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` in the `SELECT`.

Comment: `Case when Ptypecd =  'I' then C.PCD Else O.PCD end as PCD` [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that joins two tables conditionally, in your case you need to join the `Customer` table when the `PTypecd` of `Invoice` is `1` so add another condition for joint statement `AND I.PTypecd = 1`, and it the other `join` you need to check wither `I.PTypecd = 0` and that will let you join the other table `Organization`

```
SELECT I.PCD, I.PtypeCD
FROM Invoice I
LEFT JOIN Customer a ON a.CustomerCD = i.PDC AND I.PTypecd = 1
LEFT JOIN Organization b ON b.Organization = i.PDC AND i.PTypecd = 0;
```